# Discord.js some GuildMemeber functions don't work or?

Tags: discord, mute, discord.js

Anyone knows what could be the issue that .kick() .setMute(true/false) or even setDeaf(true/false) in discord.js libary don't seem to work. Here is also a part of the code that doesn't do anything when it should but also doesn't throw any errors. Bot was invited with maximum privileges and also code block executes the command to steMute / setDeaf / kick. Any ideas of what might cause this or what should i try logging to find the issue? THANKS!

```
ar msgUserId = msg.author.id
    var allUsers = []
    var reset = true
    bot.channels.forEach((channel, id) => {
        if (reset){
            channel.members.forEach((user, id) => {
                allUsers.push(user)
                if (id == msgUserId){
                    reset = false
                }
            })
            if (reset){
                allUsers = []
            }
        }
    })

    if (allUsers){
        var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * allUsers.length))
        allUsers[number].setDeaf(true)
        allUsers[number].setMute(true)
    } else {
        var channel = msg.channel
        channel.send("You must be in a voice channel with others for this to work!")
    }
```

Comment: ar msgUserId = msg.author.id should be `var msgUserId = msg.author.id`  is that a paste issue or a code issue?

Comment: It is a paste issue i thing it wouldnt even compile in other case. it is var there... will cahnge it when i get a time to hop on PC

Comment: @AleksanderPiciga - have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Channels in `bot.channels` are cached for the sole purpose of metadata which are instances of `Channel`, you need a guild context (aka. server ID) in order to acquire a `TextChannel` with which the operations you say can be done.